# interview riddle (string manipulation) - explanation needed

Tags: string, memory-management

i am studying for an interview and encountered a question + solution. 
i am having a problem with one line in the solution and was hoping maybe someone here can explain it.

the question:

> Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with ‘%20’.

the solution:

```
public static void ReplaceFun(char[] str, int length) {
    int spaceCount = 0, newLength, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ‘ ‘) {
            spaceCount++;
        }
    }
    newLength = length + spaceCount * 2;
    str[newLength] = ‘\0’;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == ‘ ‘) {
            str[newLength - 1] = ‘0’;
            str[newLength - 2] = ‘2’;
            str[newLength - 3] = ‘%’;
            newLength = newLength - 3;
        } else {
            str[newLength - 1] = str[i];
            newLength = newLength - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is with line number 9. how can he just set str[newLength] to '\0'? or in other words, how can he take over the needed amount of memory without allocating it first or something like that?
isn't he running over a memory?!

Comment: You would seem to be correct. This will result in undefined behavior because they will be writing to memory that they did not allocate. Unless they allocated much more space than the string actually occupies. You must assume they did so outside this function for this to work.

Comment: Your function probably assumes in your exercise that your array is large enough. If not, you are in trouble.

Comment: Ths code is neither C nor C++. The body of the function looks like C (and hence C++) but the declaration dors not. How the function can achieve its goal depends on the interface, though.

Comment: Tagged C++ and C, and the code is Java or C#? Pick a language, please!

Comment: Worst case: all chars are spaces. To do: always malloc 3x the length of the string for this. space -> single char  but 20% is 3 chars.

Comment: `public static` is not valid C or C++.  Also the code has smart quotes ...

Comment: I wonder why anyone would upvote this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is actually meant to be in C (`private static` is not valid C or C++), they can't, as it's written. They're never allocating a new `str` which will be long enough to hold the old string plus the `%20` expansion.

I suspect there's an additional part to the question, which is that `str` is already long enough to hold the expanded `%20` data, and that `length` is the length of the string in `str`, not counting the zero terminator.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid code, but it's not good code. You are completely correct in your assessment that we are overwriting the bounds of the initial str[]. This could cause some rather unwanted side-effects depending on what was being overwritten.